# Add cascade/delete functionality to existing migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, cascade

I have 2 `tables` in my `database`. One for `Courses` and one for `Course Chapters`.

The `migration` for the `courses` looks like this:

```php
Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The `migration` for the `chapters` looks like this:

```php
Schema::create('course_chapters', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('course_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I want the course and the chapter to `cascade down`, so when i delete a `course`, the `chapter` also will be deleted.

Some examples i saw make use of deleting the `foreign key` but I never signed my column as a `foreign key`.

For example, normally, I could:

```php
$table->dropForeign('course_id');

$table->foreign('course_id')
->references('id')->on('courses')
->onDelete('cascade');
```

How can i accomplish this in a (preferably) `new migration` and on what `table` should i add the `foreign key`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This as it is should go on your `course_chapters` table:

```
$table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses')->onDelete('cascade');
```

You don't need to add `$table->dropForeign('course_id');` because that will drop the foreign key from the column.

**NOTE**: and this:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('course_id');
```

Should be this:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('course_id');
```

Because it will throw an error of using different data types.

Comment: Thank you. Should i add the `dropForeign` in my `down()` function?

Comment: if you are making a completely new migration, then yes. But if you add this to the existing one, just dropping the table is enough.

Comment: Yes, i made a new `migration`. I added it. Thank you.

Comment: And the foreign key has a different name, not just `course_id` so you should better add this instead: `$table->dropForeign(['course_id']);` when it is array it will add the additional tables and whatnot itself.